# Case statements on where clause?

Tags: sql, case

I am a bit new to case statements but below is my query.

```
Table1
col1    col2    col3    col4    Month   Freeze
1   13  25  37  1   0
3   15  27  39  2   1
4   16  28  40  2   0
5   17  29  41  3   1
6   18  30  42  3   0
7   19  31  43  4   1
8   20  32  44  4   0
9   21  33  45  5   1
10  22  34  46  5   0
11  23  35  47  6   0
```

'Results i want like':

```
Select all records from Month1 to Month 12 where 'Freeze = 1' ,
if any month between 1 to 12 does not have Freeze = 1 then give me records for Freeze= 0 'just for the months which does not have 'Freeze = 1'
```

My best non-working attempt:

```
select * from tb1 where Month between 2 and 6 and freeze = 1 or Month in ('1' ,'2') and freeze = 0
```

Comment: Please show us your best non-working attempt.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: My  Query is: select * from tb1
where Month between  2 and 6 and freeze = 1
or  Month in ('1' ,'2') and freeze = 0

Comment: I am not sure how to achieve results for my condition

Comment: Are the `col` values ever null?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using an `outer join`:

```
select t1.*
from Table1 t1
  left join Table1 t2 on 
    t1.month = t2.month and t2.freeze = 1
where t1.freeze = 1
    and t1.month between 1 and 12 
    or t2.month is null
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/821d9/9)

Results:

```
COL1  COL2  COL3   COL4  MONTH  FREEZE
1     13      25   37    1      0
3     15      27   39    2      1
5     17      29   41    3      1
7     19      31   43    4      1
9     21      33   45    5      1
11    23      35   47    6      0
```

Note, depending on your data, you may need to use `distinct` with this method.

Comment: Thanks a LOT all for your time!! all the answers are usefull.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a method that uses standard SQL:

```
Select t1.*
from table1 t1
where Freeze = 1 and month between 1 and 12 or
      (not exists (select 1 from table where Freeze = 1 and month between 1 and 12) and
       month = 0
      );
```

Using window functions, you could also do:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             count(case when freeze = 1 and month between 1 and 2) over () as freeze1cnt
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where month between 1 and 2 and freeze = 1 or
      month = 0 and freeze1cnt = 0;
```